# Visual Studio crash when storing lot of file in wwwroot folder in ASP .NET Core project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I want to store lot of png file(>500 000 and >10G) in wwwroot in ASP. NET Core project, but if I open my project the Visual Studio 2019 crash. First I made a folder in wwwroot, then excluded this folder from project(Exclude From Project), then I coppied the png files into excluded folder. If I opened the project the Visual Studio was very slow or crashed with memory error. I do not know VS why want read this files when I excluded from the project.

How can I store these png files in wwwroot without VS crash?

Thanks

Comment: that sounds almost like the size of a big node_modules folder so that would really surprise me. but vs 2019 is a 32 bit process and is capped to 4GB process memory, i don't know if it will help, but maybe you should just try upgrading to VS 2022 wich is 64bit.

Comment: I tried it, and Visual Studio 2022 loaded the project, but it was very slow and used lot of memory (12 G), I do not understand Visual Studio what do with these files. I dont want open these files in VS, I only need these files for my program.

Comment: something else you could do is setting up an other [File Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) to serve static files from an directory outside of your project.